# 'int' object is not callable in for in range loop

Tags: python, loops, opencv

so i am using loops to get each pixels in an image, but i am getting an error which i don't understand.I am using for in range loop to do this

```
height,width=img.shape
```

when i log these it gives the result alright. The dimensions are being logged, but then when i loop it gives error. I have seen a lot of code use this, but now it is giving some error. What is happening here?

```
for i in range(0, height):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The code for the loop looks like:

```
p =[]
p.append(5000)
p.append(0)
p.append(5000)
p.append(0)
for i in range(0, height):
  for j in range(0, width):
    if mask[i][j]==0:
        if i<p[0]:
            p[0]=i
        if i>p[1] :
            p[1] = i
        if j<p[2]:
            p[2]=j
        if j>p[3] :
            p[3] = j
    else:
        img[i,j]=[255,255,255]
```

Comment: The code as it is works without any error, still something is missing from your code!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code you posted works just fine. Please, make sure that you create a [mcve] which accurately reproduces the problem in the most minimal way possible without requiring any external resources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have redefined the `range` name into an int, if you do `type(range)` it will return `int` instead of `range`

You can even get back to the old method using this lines of code :

```py
range = 5  # Oh no ! I made a mistake !


import builtins
range = builtins.range  # Get back the original method
```